# Why is QuickBooks API not returning a refresh token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

I'm trying to setup a quickbooks integration with our rails app and I'm getting very weird results. So far, I've created an Active Admin page that lets me call out to Quickbooks' API to get an Oauth2 token:

```
  action_item :reset_token do
    session[:state] = SecureRandom.uuid
    quickbook_params = {
      response_type: 'code',
      state: session[:state],
      scope: 'com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting'
    }
    link_to "Reset Token", client.authorization_uri(quickbook_params)
  end

  page_action :oauth2_redirect do
    # test if the response has the state that we set to prevent a man-in-the-middle attack
    if session[:state] == params[:state]
      client.authorization_code = params[:code]
      resp = client.access_token!
      ENV["QBO_API_REALM_ID"] = params[:realmId]
      ENV["QBO_API_REFRESH_TOKEN"] = resp.refresh_token
      ENV["QBO_API_ACCESS_TOKEN"] = resp.access_token
    end
    redirect_to admin_quickbooks_path
  end
```

```
def client
  Rack::OAuth2::Client.new(
    identifier: ENV['QBO_API_IDENTIFIER'],
    secret: ENV['QBO_API_SECRET'],
    redirect_uri: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url + ENV['QBO_API_REDIRECT_URI'],
    authorization_endpoint: ENV["QBO_API_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT"],
    token_endpoint: ENV["QBO_API_TOKEN_ENDPOINT"]
  )
end
```

The above "works" in that I get an access token (but no refresh token). the `realm_id` also matches the company id that I'm expecting so it seems to be recognizing the authorization attempt at least.

But, I'm not getting back a `refresh_token` and I keep getting 500s when I try to use the `access_token` to retrieve a customer:

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: bearer $auth_token" "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/$realm_id/customer/1"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd"><Message>Internal Server Error</Message><ErrorCode>500</ErrorCode><Cause>SERVER</Cause></FaultInfo>
```

Which is the same error I see in my logs when I try to run a query from the rails app:

```
  action_item :run_query do
    link_to "Run Query", admin_quickbooks_query_path
  end

  page_action :query do
    QboApi.log = true # TODO: clean up so that we aren't always logging the Quickbooks API
    if ENV['QBO_API_ACCESS_TOKEN']
      qbo_api = QboApi.new(
        access_token: ENV['QBO_API_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
        realm_id: ENV['QBO_API_REALM_ID']
      )
      session[:qb_customer] = qbo_api.get :customer, 1 rescue "-- rescued error --"
    end
    redirect_to admin_quickbooks_path
  end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there no debug/request log on the developer portal/side of Quickbooks?

Comment: @JoshBrody I don't see any kind of server side logs that I can get from Quickbooks.